# Remove any returns/newlines between two strings

Tags: linux, text, sed

I am on the last step of my showtimes script that pulls my local theatres info and converts it to a clean text format. I have added some "flags" and I want to remove any returns that may exist between the beginning and ending flag, and most likely replace them with a space.

Current output:

```
|startStart| Sat Nov 11, 1:00 4:10 |endEnd|
|startStart| Sun Nov 12, 1:00 4:10 |endEnd|
|startStart| Mon Nov 13, 5:50 |endEnd|
|startStart| Tue Nov 14, 5:50 |endEnd|
|startStart| Wed
Nov 15, 5:50 |endEnd|
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I can't find a similar problem using google. I would like to use SED if possible since that is what is used in the rest of the script and that is the program I am currently learning.

I would like the output to look like this:

```
|startStart| Sat Nov 11, 1:00 4:10 |endEnd|
|startStart| Sun Nov 12, 1:00 4:10 |endEnd|
|startStart| Mon Nov 13, 5:50 |endEnd|
|startStart| Tue Nov 14, 5:50 |endEnd|
|startStart| Wed Nov 15, 5:50 |endEnd|
```

Comment: You can do this using the hold space, but it will be easier in other languages like `awk`.

Comment: Can you provide the awk example?

Comment: No, I'm not going to write it for you, but I'll explain the logic. Test if the current line ends with `|endEnd|`. If not, save the current line in a variable. If it does, concatenate the current line with the variable, print that result, then empty the variable.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks @barmar. So that will help me enough to get something on paper I think. Does this logic sound correct to you? Find line that begins with |startStart|, check is it ends in |endEnd|. If it doesn't, write it to variable and delete original line. find the following line that ends in |endEnd| and append the variable to the front of it. OR is it possible to just remove the return at the end of the |startStart| line?

Comment: You don't search for lines when using `sed` and `awk`. They process the file sequentially.

Comment: You can, however, filter the lines with a pattern, ie `awk '/^|startStart|/{do something here, only on startStart lines}' file` (Using `|` in your pattern may confuse the pattern recognizer, you may need `\|` instead. Good luck.

Comment: If you're going to do more of this, you'll do well to read and practice the [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)  and less so, the [sed tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) . Good luck.

Comment: Arg, I think I misread your problem. So is the only issue that you want to "close up" the last 2 lines, so they appear as one line? It seems like it would be better to debug this at the beginning and fix it there. Include inputs that create your current output (with errors) AND your code, and we can help you fix that. Good luck.

Comment: OK, this is what I have so far. I am working on identifying line that start with timesStart but do not end with timesEnd. It seems to have no impact. `sed -i '/timesEnd$/! s/^timesStart.*/& fixThisOne/' /tmp/showtimes.raw`

Comment: Your question has downvotes, partly because you did not add your attempt to the question. Please add your comment with what you have in the question. And check the strings `timesEnd`, `timesStart`, they are different from `|startStart|` and `|endEnd|`

Answer (score 2):

If it is always the case that `|startStart|` is followed by `|endEnd|`, then this should work:

```
sed '
    /|startStart|/ {
        :a
        /|endEnd|/! {
            N
            ba
        }
        s/\n/ /g
    }
' inputfile >outputfile
```

- when a line containing start tag is seen:

  - until a line containing end tag is seen

    - append next line to the pattern space
  - strip any newlines

Answer (score 1):

When each line should have a `|startStart|...|endEnd|`, replace all `\n` with a space and append a newline after each `|endEnd|`.

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file | sed -r 's/\|endEnd\| /&\n/g'
```

Or with the `-z` option

```
sed -rz 's/\n/ /g;s/\|endEnd\| /&\n/g' file
```

Edit:
After the change above, each line will end with a space. Don't use `&`:

```
sed -rz 's/\n/ /g;s/(\|endEnd\|) /\1\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/|endEnd|$/!{N;s/\n/ /;ba}' file
```

Set a goto point called `a`.

If a line does not end in `|endEnd|`, then append the next line and replace the newline between them with a space.

Go to `a`

N.B. The `N` command will terminate processing if there is no next line, thus if the data is incomplete, an erroneous record will be output.